# After executing these commands, something wrong with "resolv.conf" file

Tags: 18.04

After executing these commands, writes : /etc/resolv.conf : No such file or directory. 
These commands:

m /etc/resolv.conf
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

Now I can not connect the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands you provided in your question doesn't make much sense, I don't know a command `m`, also the `ln`-command is incomplete as it is unclear in which directory the link is created. Without specifying a link-name, the link will be created in the current directory and has the same name as the target.

My guess is you ran `rm /etc/resolv.conf` which is a link to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

To restore the deleted link run

```
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

as root and you should be able to connect to the internet.